# meaning of にしてみたら

Tags: translation, meaning

what means にしてみたら with 俺 in this phrase?

> 俺にしてみたら精一杯{せいいっぱい}やってんだよ

Comment: What do you think it means in this sentence?

Comment: ㋕…であると判断をくだす。みなす。また、決定する。選んでそれに決める。「まあ、これでよしとしよう」「友をよき競争相手とする」「出場を取りやめにする」「私は、[コ]{、}[ー]{、}[ヒ]{、}[ー]{、}[に]{、}[す]{、}[る]{、}」([する](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/120514/meaning/m0u/する/))

Comment: @変幻出没 3の ㋒『（「…とする」「…とすれば」「…としては」「…にしては」などの形で）…と仮定する、… **の立場** ・レベル・段階**で考える** 、などの意を表す。・・・「親**としては**心配するのは当然だ」』←こっちです。。

Comment: @chocolate, Thank you, I still need to brush up my dictionary browsing skill.

Comment: Then it only means something like "for me"?

Comment: @Veron Well I think it can mean "seen from the position I am in" "if you ask me" "in my opinion" "from my viewpoint" "from the way I see it" (like「私の立場から 言えば/見れば」)  depending on the context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

“XXにしてみたら” means "from someone’s standpoint / for one’s own part." So ”俺にしてみたら精一杯やってんだよ” means “On my part, I’ve been making my best.

“….にしてみたら”　can be used in the following ways for examples:

俺にしてみたら、君と仕事を代わって貰いたいよ - For me, I’d like to change my job with you.

見習いの身にしてみたら、親方の小言は辛いよ - As a trainee, my boss’s harsh words are really bitter to me.

親にしてみたら、息子がぐれてるのは辛いよー From his parent’s standpoint, it’s painful to see their son has gone bad.

彼女にしてみたら、もっと旦那にやさしくして貰いたかったんだ - For her own part, she must have wished her husband to be more loving.